# Can a non FAA CFI (EASA for eg) sign off a high performance endorsement on an FAA PPL certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations

I have an FAA PPL cert, flying in the UK. Can a qualified EASA CFI sign off a high performance endorsement on my FAA certificate. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Aviation SE!  This is a very good first question.

Answer (score 3):

No, the problem is that the endorsement must come from an "authorized instructor" which is defined in [61.1(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.1):

> Authorized instructor means -
>
> (i) A person who holds a ground instructor certificate issued under part 61 of this chapter and is in compliance with § 61.217, when conducting ground training in accordance with the privileges and limitations of his or her ground instructor certificate;
>
> (ii) A person who holds a flight instructor certificate **issued under part 61 of this chapter** and is in compliance with § 61.197, when conducting ground training or flight training in accordance with the privileges and limitations of his or her flight instructor certificate; or
>
> (iii) A person authorized by the Administrator to provide ground training or flight training under part 61, 121, 135, or 142 of this chapter when conducting ground training or flight training in accordance with that authority.

The requirement for an "authorized instructor" comes from [61.31](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.31):

> (f)Additional training required for operating high-performance airplanes.
>
> (1) Except as provided in paragraph (f)(2) of this section, no person may act as pilot in command of a high-performance airplane (an airplane with an engine of more than 200 horsepower), unless the person has -
>
> (i) Received and logged ground and flight training **from an authorized instructor** in a high-performance airplane, or in a flight simulator or flight training device that is representative of a high-performance airplane, and has been found proficient in the operation and systems of the airplane; and
>
> (ii) Received a one-time endorsement in the pilot's logbook **from an authorized instructor** who certifies the person is proficient to operate a high-performance airplane.

So you can't get an endorsement from a "CFI" who is not authorized under [Part 61](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/part-61/subpart-H).